# How to fix SSLHandShakeException in Android

Tags: java, android, http, ssl, https

Im having a problem with sending request to my server with HTTPS protocol. It throws an exception

`com.androidnetworking.error.ANError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed`

But HTTP protocol is working fine. I'm using socket to send data to server. And also in logcat I saw this error

`SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER`

I've done few research and found few solutions but none of them work for me.

Comment: it always better to add some screenshot

Comment: These are too few information to debug the problem. It might be that SSL is not properly setup in the first place or that you are trying to access HTTPS on the same port you access HTTP. Or something different. Please look at the many many questions here about SSL problems with Java and what kind of detail is needed to debug the problem and how you can provide this detail.

Comment: On Android it is important to know on why Android version(s) you have executed your code and got that error message. You should also edit your question and add some more info on your app - what networking libraries does it use, or how to you establish the HTTPS connection.